# Java: What's the best way to generate several independent GUIs?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I need to display multiple images so that users may compare them and I'm not sure what method to use.  I have an app that allows the user to choose image files so I have a File Object.  I've tried to generate new GUIs with "new" but that doesn't work well.

Should I code a standalone app (with a main) and use a system call to start them with a new JVM?
I'm new at Java and have just touched the surface of AWT and SWING.

The class is called thus where name is an arbitrary unique String:

```
ImageWindowStub iw = new ImageWindowStub(name);
```

Here is simple code that demonstrates the problem if called in succession.

```
package fireScience.airborne.image;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class ImageWindowStub {


private static JFrame frame;
private static JPanel statusPanel;
private static JLabel statPixInfoLbl;

private static String theString;

public ImageWindowStub(String theString) {
    this.theString = theString;
    statusPanel = new JPanel();
    createAndShowGui();

}

private static void createAndShowGui() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame = new JFrame(theString);
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            frame.setResizable(true);
            frame.setSize(300, 200);
            frame.setLocation(50, 50);
            statusPanel = new JPanel();
            statusPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
            statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), 24));
            statusPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statusPanel,
                    BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            statPixInfoLbl = new JLabel("Status Bar");
            statPixInfoLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            statusPanel.add(statPixInfoLbl);
            frame.add(statusPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}

}
```

My core question is "What is the best way to generate multiple independent instances of a GUI class?"

Comment: "I've tried to generate new GUIs with `new` but that doesn't work well". What does "doesn't work well" mean? What did you call `new` on? You probably want to create multiple JFrames

Comment: Sometimes the best way to do something is to hire an expert, who is paid to listen to you, figure out what you want, and deliver it.

Comment: See [*Working with Images*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) and then edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"multiple images so that users may compare them"*  Do they need to be visible in pairs at one time?  `JScrollPane` If can be shown individually, a `JList` and `CardLayout` or a `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not explicit enough.  The first GUI (JFrame) displays correctly, subsequent ones are a different color, there are no icons for maximize, minimize, and exit but there are icon "holders" visible but on the opposite side of the window from where they should be for Ubuntu, and the window doesn't have the rounded upper corners that the standard Ubuntu windows have.  I interpreted this to mean I was not doing this correctly.

Comment: That I want to create an image is not the core issue but I appreciate the link.  I do want track mouse position when I do have an image and do want a popup menu.  I should not have tagged my question with image.

Comment: The GUI/Window is created thus:

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you want are [internal frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).  Each internal frame would have a main `JPanel` that contains one `JLabel` holding an `ImageIcon`.

You can tile or overlay internal frames, depending on what you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer, not quite what I wanted, but it appears to work.
I added a main which takes a string argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        ImageWindowStub iws = new ImageWindowStub(args[0]);
    } else {
        ImageWindowStub iws = new ImageWindowStub("Testing: No arg passed");
    }
}
```

I then exported an executable jar file and create an instance  thus:

```
            Process p;
            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Where "command" is a string with the fully qualified path name to the executable jar plus the argument.

So far it appears that I can create multiple instances discarding the previous value of p.  The displayed frames don't exit when the calling program does but it appears that this behavior can be implemented.